# Какой алгоритм для решения задачи нужно использовать?

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить следующую задачу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```
length = 0
x = '14 21 26 10 -9 -10 0 20 11 8 5 27 5 15 23 -7 18 3 2'
y = '2 -7 28 21 -6 21 10 24 -5 15 16 17 3 25 10 28 11 26 19'
lfx=[float(i) for i in x.split()]
difx = lfx[0]
for n in lfx[1:]:
    difx -= n
print(difx)
lfy=[float(i) for i in y.split()]
dify = lfy[0]
for n in lfy[1:]:
    dify -= n
print(dify)
length=(difx*difx+dify*dify)**(0.5)
print('{:.2f}'.format(length))
```

но тут не верный ответ. я думаю что не правильный алгоритм ииспользую
. подскажите пожалуйста как правильно

Comment: Ну, видимо, нужно посчитать расстояния между **каждой парой точек** и сложить их.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создаем списки.

```
x_arr = list(map(int, x.split()))
y_arr = list(map(int, y.split()))
```

2. Перебираем индексы списков, начиная с индекса `1`.

```
for i in range(1, len(x_arr)):
```

3. Считаем длину отдельно отрезка.

```
line = ((x_arr[i]-x_arr[i-1])**2 + (y_arr[i]-y_arr[i-1])**2)**.5
```

4. Добавляем длину отрезка к длине ломаной.

```
length += line
```

5. Выводим результат

```
print(length)
```